# Eclipse E4 EventService not unregistered if object is uninjected

Tags: eclipse, events, e4

I am creating a jface dialog which listens to e4 events by registering via injection:

```
@Inject
@Optional
public void process(@UIEventTopic("someEvent") final Object unused)
```

I inject the dialog like so:

```
ContextInjectionFactory.inject(myDialog, context);
```

Now, once I close the dialog, I would like to unregister from the event service. I tried calling the uninject method, but it does not seem to have any effect.

```
ContextInjectionFactory.uninject(myDialog, context);
```

What is the correct way of unregistering?

Comment: In my experience JFace dialogs don't really fit in to parts of the injection system like UIEventTopic, you might have better luck using the `subscribe` and `unsubscribe` methods of `IEventBroker`.